# Best way to expose templated base classes in Boost Python?

Tags: python, c++, boost

I have a OO pattern that looks like this:

```
class Base
{/*some pure virtual functions*/};

template < typename T>
class Derived : public Base
{/*some pure virtual functions*/};

class SomeOtherClass
{};

class SecondDerived : public Derived<SomeOtherClass>
{};
```

I have many classes that inherit from Derived with a bunch of other classes. I'm trying to figure out what is the cleanest way to expose all of these different "SecondDerived" classes to Python. Boost requires that the base class be exposed. So far, I've come up with a decent way to expose all the common member functions:

```
// This is a templatized utility function that can do the most common expose operations
template < class SecondDerivedType, class TemplateParamter>
object create_secondderived_type()
{
    // first expose the Derived<SomeOtherClass> class
    object obj_base = class_<Derived<TemplateParameter>, bases<Base>> (name, no_init);

    // then the actual class may be exposed
    object obj_class = class_<SecondDerivedType, bases<Derived<TemplateParameter>>>(other_name)
        .def("common_function", &SecondDerivedType::common_function)
        ;

    // then you can return the object, but it seems to have little value
    return obj_class;
}


BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(mymodule)
{
    // Within Boost Python, you just call the function with the templated arguments.
    object obj = create_secondderived_type<SecondDerived, SomeOtherClass>();
}
```

The problem that I'm running into is that the SecondDerived-like classes might have their own member functions that I'd want to expose, but so far my understanding of Boost Python is that you need to expose all the member functions in one go. I've asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36851717/add-member-functions-to-a-boost-python-class-after-the-fact) if that's true, and if it's not then that should sufficiently solve my problem, but I wonder if there's a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with my answer on your other question, don't return `object` - return the correct `class_` specialization:

```
template < class SecondDerivedType, class TemplateParamter>
class_<SecondDerivedType, bases<Derived<TemplateParameter>>>
create_secondderived_type()
{
    // first expose the Derived<SomeOtherClass> class
    object obj_base = class_<Derived<TemplateParameter>, bases<Base>> (name, no_init);

    // then the actual class may be exposed
    auto derived = class_<SecondDerivedType, bases<Derived<TemplateParameter>>>(other_name)
        .def("common_function", &SecondDerivedType::common_function)
        ;

    return derived;
}
```

And then you can just add whatever member functions you want:

```
create_secondderived_type<SecondDerived, SomeOtherClass>()
    .def("specific_function", &SecondDerived::specific_function)
;
```